# File URI with username and password in Explorer

Tags: passwords, file-sharing, url, windows-explorer, uri

How to specify file URI with user name and password in the (Windows File) Explorer, please?

Something like `file://domain\user:password@host/dir/file`. I need to specify `domain` to be equal `host` name, because domain user name is used instead.

It is possible to write `file://host/dir/file` and fill credentials in interactive dialog, but an automated process is to be designed.

When URI starts with `smb:` or `cifs:` then Explorer writes "No program associated…".

Answer (score 0):

You could store the credentials (pw and username) for a host in the Credentials Manager in the control panel (Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager for Windows 8.1 but this goes all the way down to at least Vista). That way you needn't provide the credentials with the URL.

(Where do you specify this? It is a no-no to store passwords in plain text.)

Comment: In secret securized documentation for a small team it is needed to specify how to access (with which credentials) different shared folders.